# React Navigation: Sibling Modals each with their own navigator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, modal-dialog, react-navigation

**Problem**

I have a React Native app with the following React Navigation navigator structure:

- Top level `NavigationContainer`

  - Modal with Stack Navigator
  - Modal with Stack Navigator
  - Tab Navigator

    - Stack Navigator

I've also included a code example below showing the navigators structures.

I'm running into the error that I have multiple navigators under a single `NavigationContainer` when I add the second modal with a stack navigator inside it.  I don't need the stack navigators inside each modal to navigate outside of their stack or be navigated to by a navigator outside of their stack.  I believe the correct solution is to wrap each Stack Navigator in each modal in its own `NavigationContainer` with `independent={true}`, however I'm not sure as [React Navigation's docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-container/#independent) warn that you typically don't want to use this.

**Question**

1. Is there something wrong with my navigator structure?
2. Is this a good situation to use independent Navigation Containers?

**Code**

Note: In reality the are more non navigator components between ComponentA and where the actual navigators are in the react tree but I've simplified it for this example.

```
export const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <ComponentA />  // Contains 2 sibling modals, each with their own Stack Navigator
      <ComponentB /> // Contains a tab navigator with a nested stack navigator
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}

const ComponentA = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Modal>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen />
          <Stack.Screen />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </Modal>
      <Modal>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen />
          <Stack.Screen />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </Modal>
    </>
  )
}

const ComponentB = () => {
  return (
    <Modal>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen component={ComponentC} />
        <Tab.Screen />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </Modal>
  )
}

const ComponentC = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigation>
      <Stack.Screen />
      <Stack.Screen />
    </Stack.Navigation>
  )
}
```